# Apple Watch workout for a standing-desk treadmill?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, fitness+

Any tips for getting this to work properly? I select "Indoor Walk" but my Apple Watch routinely thinks I've stopped working out and asks me to either Pause or End Workout, and my step count in the Apple Watch is more than 50% lower than what my treadmill records. I've tried manually entering in my step count recorded by my treadmill in the Health app but it seems to me that my rings don't adjust to account for the manual entry.

I'm usually typing when I walk on the treadmill, but I try to "sway" my arm normally when I'm not. I also make an effort to have my iPhone in my pocket thinking maybe it'll pick up my leg movement. There's also the fact that my workout summary says 0 distance traveled, I'm assuming because GPS showed me being stationary the whole time.

I'm bummed I don't close my move ring after a 4 hour walk/16k+ steps...

Comment: Does your treadmill happen to have an iOS app that can share data with Fitness?

Comment: No. I have a TR800-DT3.

Comment: I have the same problem, would be great to find a workaround.